# Java Date Formatter not working while saving Excel date data into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, excel, date

My goal is to save every rows of data in excel into MySQL database. In my excel file, the date format is dd.MM.yyyy, whereas yyyy-MM-dd is the date format in MySQL.

Here are my codes:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/activity", "root", "password");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstm = null ;
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("testing.xlsx");
            //POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                String activityName= row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue();
                Integer activityAllocation = (int) row.getCell(8).getNumericCellValue();
                //DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
                //String activityDate = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(10));
                Date activityDate = row.getCell(10).getDateCellValue();                
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                String Date = sdf.format(activityDate);
                String activityPersonInCharge = row.getCell(11).getStringCellValue();

                String sql = "INSERT INTO activity(ACTIVITY_NAME,ACTIVITY_ALLOCATION,ACTIVITY_DATE,ACTIVITY_MADE_BY) VALUES('"+activityName+"','"+activityAllocation +"','"+activityDate +"','"+activityPersonInCharge +"')";
                pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.execute();
                System.out.println("Import rows "+i);
            }
            con.commit();
            pstm.close();
            con.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to format the date of the excel cell but failed to work. The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.typeMismatch(XSSFCell.java:1062)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getNumericCellValue(XSSFCell.java:307)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.getDateCellValue(XSSFCell.java:776)
    at ExcelReader.main(ExcelReader.java:35)
```

Which part of the codes that I did wrongly? Also, if I use the commented line of codes for the date formatter, no exception shown but it save the wrong dates. Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Doing nothing more than reading the exception, you seem to be trying to read a numeric value from a text based cell - have you tried reading it as a `String` instead (and seeing what it returns)?

Comment: You should inserting an actual date object into your database, rather than a formatted string ... but you're not using `PreparedStatement` properly anyway :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried with String, but it saves the wrong date into MySQL. For instance, in the excel, the date is 19.06.2014 but in MySQL is 2019-06-20.

Comment: @ScaryWombat line 35 is Date activityDate = row.getCell(10).getDateCellValue();

Comment: @atomSmasher It shows 'Cannot cast from String to int'

Comment: And? So you need to convert the `String` to a `Date` object, then using that, apply it to your `PreparedStatement` and update the database - to me, this is more about you not [understanding how to use `PreapredStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) then any thing else - You should stop trying to insert "formatted strings" into databases and start making use of the JDBC drivers support for date/times types

Comment: Sorry, wrong line... I meant change Date activityDate = row.getCell(10).getDateCellValue(); to String activityDateString = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();

Comment: If there is any way you can, which there is, stay away from the old and outdated classes `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Their modern replacements are so much nicer to work with. Once you've got your date as string from Excel, use `LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateAsString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu"));` and then `ps.setObject(3, date);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the value as a String

```
String activityDate = row.getCell(10).getStringCellValue();
```

According to you the format is`19.06.2014`

so

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

then parse it into a Date

```
Date dt = sdf.parse(activityDate);
```

Use PreparedStatment to insert

Set the value (column 3 ?)

```
ps.setDate (3, dt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. There is an error at the last step: "The method setDate(int, Date) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (int, String)". The activityDate is a String data type. Should I change it to Date?

Comment: Read again Brian `ps.setDate (3, dt);`  `dt` is a Date, however you will need to convert to a java.sql.Date `new java.sql.Date (dt.getTime())`